# Hidden field not being generated from helper in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement a nested form using the allows_nested_attributes_for feature in rails3 to implement a survey form. Survey has many questions has many answers.

I want to pass the :_destroy field as hidden and use jQuery to set it when a link is clicked. It was working fine but when I tried doing the same using a helper method, the hidden field doesn't show up.

```
module ApplicationHelper
   def link_to_remove_field(link_text, builder)
   builder.hidden_field :_destroy
   link_to link_text, '#',  :class=>"remove_field"
  end
end
```

This is the jquery function I want to use.

```
$(function(){
  $('.remove_field').on('click', function(element){
  $(this).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
  $(this).parent('.field').hide();
  return false;
  });
});
```

And this is partial from which I am calling the helper

```
<%= f.label :question %><br />
<%= f.text_area :question, :rows=>1 %>
<%= link_to_remove_field("Remove question", f) %>
```

The a tag appears but the hidden field doesn't show.

```
<textarea cols="40" id="old_question_set_old_questions_attributes_2_question" name="old_question_set[old_questions_attributes][2][question]" rows="1"></textarea>
<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove question</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `link_to_remove_field` is only returning the last line which is the `link_to` because you forgot to add the `hidden_field`.  change your helper to

```
def link_to_remove_field(link_text, builder)
  builder.hidden_field(:_destroy) +
  link_to(link_text, '#', :class => "remove_field")
end
```

please take note that you may need to call `html_safe` when calling this method

```
link_to_remove_field(....).html_safe
```

Comment: The problem got fixed when I put brackets around :_destroy and link_to.

Isn't ruby supposed to work without the brackets?

I'm a ruby noob. Why do you have to add the '+' sign after each line in a helper?